# "tar: unrecognized option --warning" during 'apt-get install'

Tags: debian, upgrade, apt, tar

I just ran `apt-get upgrade` on my debian 5 vps and I got this error:

> tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'

Now when I try to install other packages e.g: imagemagick I get the same error:

```
li197-162:~# apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pkg-config comerr-dev libssh2-1-dev libpcre3-dev libdb4.6-dev libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient15-dev libldap2-dev libpcrecpp0 libexpat1-dev libpq5 libidn11-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config imagemagick-common libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libglib2.0-0 libice6 libjasper1 libjpeg8 liblcms1 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7 libmagickcore4 libmagickwand4 libpng12-0 libsm6 libtiff4
  libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxml2 libxml2-dev libxt6 ttf-dejavu-core x11-common
Suggested packages:
  imagemagick-doc autotrace cups-bsd lpr lprng enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads hp2xx html2ps libwmf-bin mplayer povray radiance sane-utils texlive-base-bin transfig xdg-utils libjasper-runtime
  liblcms-utils
Recommended packages:
  libmagickcore4-extra ghostscript netpbm ufraw-batch libglib2.0-data shared-mime-info gsfonts xml-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config imagemagick imagemagick-common libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libice6 libjasper1 libjpeg8 liblcms1 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7 libmagickcore4 libmagickwand4 libpng12-0 libsm6 libtiff4
  libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxt6 ttf-dejavu-core x11-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglib2.0-0 libxml2 libxml2-dev
3 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/11.2MB of archives.
After this operation, 22.4MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
x11-common template parse error: Template parse error near `Choices-sr@latin.UTF-8: Samo glavni korisnik, Samo za korisnike konzole, Svako', in stanza #1 of /tmp/x11-common.template.65052

tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.4.6-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-dejavu-core_2.33-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fontconfig-config_2.8.0-3_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libfontconfig1_2.8.0-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/x11-common_1%3a7.6+9_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libice6_2%3a1.0.7-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.46-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libsm6_2%3a1.2.0-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8c-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxau6_1%3a1.0.6-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.0-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxcb1_1.7-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libx11-data_2%3a1.4.4-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libx11-6_2%3a1.4.4-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxext6_2%3a1.3.0-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxt6_1%3a1.1.1-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-0_2.28.6-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms1_1.19.dfsg-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/liblqr-1-0_0.4.1-1.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libltdl7_2.4-4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjasper1_1.900.1-10_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-common_8%3a6.6.9.7-5_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagickcore4_8%3a6.6.9.7-5+b1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagickwand4_8%3a6.6.9.7-5+b1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick_8%3a6.6.9.7-5+b1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.4.6-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-dejavu-core_2.33-2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fontconfig-config_2.8.0-3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfontconfig1_2.8.0-3_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/x11-common_1%3a7.6+9_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libice6_2%3a1.0.7-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.46-3_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsm6_2%3a1.2.0-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8c-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxau6_1%3a1.0.6-3_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.0-3_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxcb1_1.7-3_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libx11-data_2%3a1.4.4-2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libx11-6_2%3a1.4.4-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxext6_2%3a1.3.0-3_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxt6_1%3a1.1.1-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-4_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-4_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-0_2.28.6-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms1_1.19.dfsg-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liblqr-1-0_0.4.1-1.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libltdl7_2.4-4_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjasper1_1.900.1-10_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-common_8%3a6.6.9.7-5_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagickcore4_8%3a6.6.9.7-5+b1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagickwand4_8%3a6.6.9.7-5+b1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick_8%3a6.6.9.7-5+b1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
li197-162:~#
```

I really have no idea what is wrong and how to fix this. Is it possible to undo an `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: what version does "apt-cache policy x11-common" list for "Candidate".  I ask because I suspect that you might be upgrading a debian 5 (currently "oldstable") server using sources pointing at debian 6 (currently "stable").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just had exactly this problem.  As Gilles suggested, upgrading `tar` is the answer but (surprise surprise) `tar` can't be upgraded in the usual way because `dpkg` requires version 1.23 or later before it'll unpack and install the latest `tar` deb. `dpkg` really needs an explicit dependency to ensure that when a later version of `dpkg` is installed, the latest `tar` version goes on first, but I guess it's a risk with combining different testing and unstable releases in unsupported ways. It's still undesirable and this seems an unfortunate way to cripple a system.

My first idea was to look for the latest binary of `tar` [at the GNU project](http://www.gnu.org/s/tar/#downloading), but unfortunately they only have source downloads, which aren't helpful if (like me) you don't have the various compiling tools installed.

If you download the latest `tar` binary `.deb` to match your system from [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org) and drop it into a temporary place somewhere (just to be tidy), you should be able to get inside it with the `ar` command,  e.g. `ar x tar_1.26-2_amd64.deb` in my case.
Then unpack the resulting `data.tar.gz` file with a command like `tar zxvf data.tar.gz`, using your existing earlier version of `tar`, which should work as long as you don't try and do anything silly like use a `--warning` parameter that won't be available until version 1.23. :) This will then let you get at the `tar` binary, which (within the data.tar.gz file) was probably at `bin/tar`.
Having done this, I added the path for that binary to the front the `PATH` variable in my shell, which in my bash shell could be done with the command `export PATH=/root/temp/bin:$PATH`, but adjust the path to fit wherever the new `tar` binary is now sitting. After that, running a regular `dpkg --install tar_1.26-2_amd64.deb` worked wonders, because `dpkg` will look in the path and find the latest `tar` binary before it finds the older version in the regular `bin` path.

Comment: Worked for me. For those that reach this page debugging installing Debian on an NSLU2, you need this .deb file: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/armel/tar/download

You can use another machine (mac okay) to do the "ar" bit above. I use curl to sync to my NSLU.

Thanks again izogi.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have `ar` on my system, so I did this horrible kludge:

```sh
mv /bin/tar /bin/tar.real
echo "tar.real xpf -" >/bin/tar
chmod +x /bin/tar
cd /
# put in the correct path
dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/tar_1.26-4_armel.deb .
# check things are working and then
#rm /bin/tar.real
```

Comment: +1. I needed this question answered when an upgrade was badly broken enough that I had only an old ‘tar’ and no ‘ar’ at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to worry about downloading the tar package.

Chances are, to get to this point because you were in the middle of an upgrade, and your package management system will have already downloaded the latest tar package for you, so it will be waiting for you in:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/tar_(version-release_platform).deb
```

e.g.:

```
# ls -t /var/cache/apt/archives/tar_*|head -1
```

/var/cache/apt/archives/tar_1.26-4_amd64.deb

This is how I fixed my system:

Find the latest version on your system:

```
root@host:~# ls -t /var/cache/apt/archives/tar_*|head -1
/var/cache/apt/archives/tar_1.26-4_amd64.deb
```

Create a temporary working area and unpack the .deb archive:

```
root@host:~# mkdir fix_tar
root@host:~# cd fix_tar
root@host:~/fix_tar# ar x /var/cache/apt/archives/tar_1.26-4_amd64.deb
```

Unpack the data.tar.gz file to find the new tar binary:

```
root@host:~/fix_tar# ls -l
total 972
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2536 2012-02-03 12:20 control.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 978996 2012-02-03 12:20 data.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      4 2012-02-03 12:20 debian-binary
root@host:~/fix_tar# tar xzf data.tar.gz
root@host:~/fix_tar# find * -name tar
bin/tar
usr/share/doc/tar
usr/lib/mime/packages/tar
```

Check the existing version on your system:

```
root@host:~/fix_tar# /bin/tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.20
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

Backup the old version in case something goes horribly wrong and you need it back:

```
root@host:~/fix_tar# mv /bin/tar /bin/tar_1.20
```

Put the new copy in place:

```
root@host:~/fix_tar# mv ./bin/tar /bin/tar
```

Check the new version:

```
root@host:~/fix_tar# /bin/tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

You're done! :-)

I was then able to carry on with another:

```
root@host:~# aptitude update
root@host:~# aptitude safe-upgrade
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest version of tar handy somewhere else (a different computer)?
If so, just `scp` it to `/usr/local/bin`, assuming `/usr/local/bin` precedes the regular `tar` in your command path.  Then, you can upgrade:

```
apt-get install tar
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing tar with the new version which was available from /var/cache... totally worked for me. I'd spent a long time trying to figure out how to fix my debian squeeze install to allow me to install new packages after messing things up by tinkering with sources list and stupidly letting webmin attempt an upgrade (bad mistake). Thanks so much to the straight to the point answers from you guys.